# How to Call Server API using certificate in JAVA

Tags: java, server, keystore

I have to call server API using certificate , So I Have imported the cer file into keystore and done coding,but still getting error as
**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

command for importing the cer file into keystore.
**keytool -importcert -file D:\KALAIVANI_ALL\kalaivani\NEW_EMANDATE_APGB\servertoservecert\onmagcert.cer -keystore D:\KALAIVANI_ALL\kalaivani\NEW_EMANDATE_APGB\servertoservecert\server_npcikeystore.jks -alias "cedge1"**

```
    appPathCertificate="D:/KALAIVANI_ALL/kalaivani/NEW_EMANDATE_APGB/servertoservecert/server_npcikeystore.jks";
                 
                  System.out.println("appPathCertificate--->"+appPathCertificate);
                  char[] passphrase = "cedge1".toCharArray(); //password
                  KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                  keystore.load(new FileInputStream(appPathCertificate), passphrase); //path
 TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                  tmf.init(keystore);


                  SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                  TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
                  context.init(null, trustManagers, null);
                  SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();
                  
             URL url = new URL(common_utility.getEmandateServerResponeURL());
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", appPathCertificate);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "cedge1");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");   
                
                String proxyhost=common_utility.getProxyHost();
                String proxyport=common_utility.getProxyPort();
                Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyhost, new Integer(proxyport)));
                HttpsURLConnection  conn = (HttpsURLConnection ) url.openConnection(proxy);
                conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sf);
                
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setUseCaches (false);
                System.out.println("GETISSUE Request : "+str_jsonparams);
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                os.write(str_jsonparams.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                 System.out.println("Response code :"+conn.getResponseCode());
```

Comment: Anyone can help pelase

Answer (score 0):

You're facing the issue with the validation of response from the server during the `SSL handshake` process. You need to add the intermediates and root certificates in the `trust store`. Those certificates will be used to validate the server identity.
For example, while making the connection, you're receiving the `stackexchange` server certificate. Then in order to validate the identity, you must have `R3 cert` (intermediate CA) and `DST Root CA X3` (Root CA) in the trust store.

[image]

```
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(keystore);

context.init(null, trustManagers, null);
```

In your case, as you're initialising `TrustManagerFactory` with `Keystore`, so you've to put the `intermediates` and `root` certificates in the Keystore. The JDK store `cacerts` won't be in use here.

Comment: Actually  I got only CER file from the destination end for accessing the URL,  as i converted into jks and passing through httpsurl connection. Whether I have to get Intermediate and root certificate also from them? how to pass that certificate also in coding. or only need to add on  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\lib\security\cacerts. This enough. Please suggest

Comment: You need the root and intermediates certificates from the target party. You can go with either approach. Add it to underlying the JDK truststore, which being utilized by your app or do as mentioned above. Create a custom truststore in your app and intialized it with the keystore file containing the certificates.